# A complex vector subspace is stable for complex conjugation if and only if it is the complexification of a real vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

A *conjugation* on a complex vector space $ U $ is a map $ c\colon U\to U $ that satisfies the following three properties:

- $ c(u + u^\prime) = c(u) + c(u^\prime) $ for every $ u,u^\prime\in U $;
- $ c(\alpha u) = \bar a c(u) $ for every $ u\in U $ and $ \alpha\in \mathbb C $;
- $ c(c(u)) = u $ for every $ u\in U $.

We write $ U_c $ for the set of all $ u\in U $ such that $ c(u) = u $.

I'm trying to show that if $ V $ is a (complex) subspace of a complex vector space $ U $ equipped with a conjugation $ c $ such that $ c(v) = V $, then $ V $ is (isomorphic to) the complexification of the real vector subspace $ V\cap U_c $.

Recall that if V is a vector space over the real numbers then it's *complexification* is a *complex* vector space $ V_{\mathbb C} $ equipped with an $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \iota\colon V\hookrightarrow V_{\mathbb C} $ such that the following universal property holds: for every complex vector space $ F $ and for every $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \phi\colon V\to F $, there exists a unique $ \mathbb C $-linear map $ \tilde\phi\colon V_{\mathbb C}\to F $ such that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>\iota>> V_{\mathbb C}\\
@| @VV\tilde\phi V \\
V @>>\phi> F
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

In my case, I want to show that $ V $ equipped with the obvious injection $ V\cap U_c\hookrightarrow V $ satisfies this universal property. Given some $ \phi\colon V\cap U_c\to F $ I tried to define $ \tilde\phi $ by noticing that a vector $ v\in V $ can be written as
$$
v = \frac{v + c(v)}{2} + \frac{v - c(v)}{2}
$$
where $ \frac{v + c(v)}2\in V\cap U_c $, and by putting
$$
\tilde\phi(v) = \phi\Bigl(\frac{v + c(v)}{2}\Bigr)\text{,}\qquad \tilde\phi(v) = \phi\Bigl(\frac{v + c(v)}{2}\Bigr) +i\phi\Bigl(\frac{v - c(v)}{2}\Bigr)\text{,}\qquad \cdots
$$
but none of this choices work.

How can I show my statement working only with the "abstract" characterization of $ V_{\mathbb C} $ I gave? (i know that $ \mathbb V_{\mathbb C}\cong \mathbb C\otimes V $, but I want to be as implementation independent as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take
$$\tilde\phi(v)=\phi\left(\frac{v + c(v)}{2}\right) + i\phi\left(\frac{v - c(v)}{2i}\right)$$
because
$$c\left(\frac{v-c(v)}{2}\right)=\frac{c(v)-c(c(v))}{2}=-\frac{v-c(v)}{2}$$
which is not in $V_c=V\cap U_c$.  On the other hand
$$c\left(\frac{v-c(v)}{2i}\right)=\frac{c(v)-c(c(v))}{2\bar{i}}=-\frac{c(v)-v}{2i} = \frac{v-c(v)}{2i}$$
so $(v-c(v))/2i\in V_c$ and you can apply $\phi$ to it and get what you need.

I don't understand why you start with $U$ and restrict to $V$.  You may as well start with $V$ (i.e. assume $V$ is all $U$.)

Comment: Whops, I forgot a bunch of $ i $s...